# Need help trying to parse a number from a UITextfield into a mathematical function which will then parse into a UISlider, controlling UISlider

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

Hey guys I am in desperate need of some help,

I am trying to parse a number from a UITextfield into a mathematical function which will then parse into a UISlider, controlling UISlider. I have been at this for 2 days, but I can't get the numbers from the UITextField to make the UISlider move, it moves on it's own though.

Thanks for the help

here is a snippet:

```
 include <math.h>
    pragma mark - User Actions




 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];

        CGFloat focal_length = [textField.text floatValue];
        CGFloat zoom =(2*atanh(4.592/(2*focal_length))*180/M_PI);
        //iPhone 5: 58.498 degrees (based upon a resolution of 3264x2448 pixels, a focal length of 4.1mm and a vertical chip size of 4.592mm)
        //2*atan(4.592/(2*4.28))*180/pi = 56.423 



     self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,zoom, zoom);

        return YES;
    }



- (IBAction)focal_length:(UITextField *)sender
{
    CGFloat focal_length = [sender.text floatValue];
    CGFloat zoom =  1 + focal_length;
    //CGFloat zoom =  1 + 4*focal_length;
    self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,zoom, zoom);
    _Slider.value = [sender.text floatValue];


}
```

`- (IBAction)zoom:(id)sender{`

```
UISlider *slider = (UISlider*)sender;
//CGFloat zoom =  1 + 4*slider.value;
CGFloat zoom = 1 + 4*slider.value;
```

`// slider.value = [UITextField.text floatValue];
    self.picker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity,zoom, zoom);
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}`

Answer (score 0):

ARe your focal_length IBAction or textFieldShouldReturn methods getting called? Add NSLog statements to the beginnings of both methods, or set breakpoints in the console and make sure they are being called.

If textFieldShouldReturn is not being called then the likely culprit is that you don't have the field's delegate set up correctly. If your focal_length IBAction method isn't being called, the cause is probably a broken IBAction link in IB.

Comment: yes, my textFieldShouldReturn is not being called, I just now verified this with NSLog statements, I control clicked the UITextField to the m.file and created a new IBAction method, and still isn't calling my textFieldShouldReturn or returning the value from the textfield. I will continue to play with it, I am fairly new to Xcode but if there are any recommendations now that we know what the problem is, that would be more than helpful.